# Sum of column by condition

Tags: r

Trying to summarize column 3 if column 1 is >.25
`if(df$V1>.25){sum(df$V3)}`   ##This returns an error In

```
    if (df$V1 > 0.25) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Any code to summarize column 3 when Column one is >.25

```
0.1287953 3 12 1
1.094262 13 14 3
0.5962845 8 17 4
0.6511204 7 19 5
0.2533915 4 6 2
0.8222555 6 18 6
0.08695875 3 7 1
0.6096232 6 6 2
1.583204 24 7 1
0.08337463 4 7 1
0.06398186 1 11 2
0.2713974 4 11 2
0.6205648 13 4 1
1.276595 15 14 3
```

Comment: You can subset the vector to sum using the condition `with(df, sum(V3[V1 > 0.25])`

Comment: Also `sum(df$V3*(df$V1>0.25))`.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to sum over the entries in column 3, where column 1 entries are > 0.25:

```
inds <- (df$V1 > 0.25)
inds
# [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Just use that to subset the third column:

```
sum( df$V3[ inds ] )
# 116
```

Or short: `sum( df$V3[ df$V1 > 0.25 ] )`